# Question with 'rbreak' command in gdb, template function not defined in source file

Tags: c++, gdb, g++

I want to set breakpoints for all type of the template function `foo`.
Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
  std::cout << t << std::endl;
}


int main() {
  foo<int>(3);
  foo<double>(3.0);
  foo<char>('c');
  return 0;
}
```

As the tutorial says [Set Breaks](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html).

I make `rbreak foo<.*>`, and it shows

```
Function "_Z3fooIcEvT_" not defined in "/home/rat/tmp/a.cpp".
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

I choose `n` for all of quizs.
I use `info breakpoints` to check breakpoints and it's empty.

I check the binary file of a.out using `nm -a|grep foo`, it shows

```
0000000000406083 W _Z3fooIcEvT_
0000000000406049 W _Z3fooIdEvT_
0000000000406015 W _Z3fooIiEvT_
```

- OS Info: Arch Linux 6.5.3-arch1-1
- g++ version: 13.2.1
- gdb version: 13.2

**I want to know whether it is correct, and if not, how to fix the issue.**

Set proper breakpoints for `foo<int>`, `foo<double>`, `foo<char>`

Comment: They likely have been inlined. Set a breakpoint in main and try list and step into. BTW you could just call `foo(3);
  foo(3.0);
  foo('c');`, CTAD would work.

Comment: Is this related to regex? If not, can you remove the tag?

Comment: Just use `break foo`.

Comment: I guess it is a gdb bug. There is a related on in the bugzilla that is open for 10 years https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15962

Comment: I don't know how to comment for each of you separately.
1. I can step into `foo` function successfully and this is just a simple demo for setting breakpoints in my project, and I don't know how to solve it now.
2. The bug do have common with my problem.
Thank you.

Comment: As a workaround, you can run `pipe rbreak foo | awk '$1 == "Function" { print "break",  $2 }' > ~/bpt.gdb` and `source ~/bpt.gdb`.